# multiple save and cek if post empty codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

i try to save 3 tables in 1 form and work, but when i check when 1 field or 2 fields empty it just save on 1 or 2 tables

```
    $data=array(
        'jenis_LP'=>$this->input->post('jenis'),
        'nama_pelapor'=>$this->input->post('pelapor'),
        'tempat_lahir'=>$this->input->post('tempat_lahir_pelapor'),
        'tgl_lahir'=>@date('Y-m-d', @strtotime($this->input->post('tanggal_lahir_pelapor'))),
        'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jns_kelamin_pelapor'),
        'pekerjaan'=>$this->input->post('pekerjaan_pelapor'),
        'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat_pelapor'),
        'telp' =>$this->input->post('telp_pelapor'),
        'agama'=>$this->input->post('agama_pelapor'),
        'kewarganegaraan' =>$this->input->post('warga_negara_pelapor'),
        'tgl_kejadian'=>@date('Y-m-d', @strtotime($this->input->post('tanggal1'))),
        'waktu_kejadian'=>$this->input->post('waktu1'),
        'tempat_kejadian'=>$this->input->post('tempat'),
        'yang_terjadi'=>$this->input->post('terjadi'),
        'bagaimana_terjadi'=>$this->input->post('kejadian'),
        'uraian_kejadian'=>$this->input->post('uraian'),
        'tindak_pidana'=>$this->input->post('pidana'),
        'barang_bukti'=>$this->input->post('bb'),
        'kerugian'=>$this->input->post('kerugian'),
        'tgl_laporan'=>@date('d-m-Y', @strtotime($this->input->post('tanggal2'))),
        'jam_lapor'=>$this->input->post('waktu2'),
        'petugas'=>$this->input->post('petugas'));

    if($this->input->post('pelaku1'))
    {
        $data1=array(
        'nama_tersangka'=>$this->input->post('pelaku1'),
        'tempat_lahir'=>$this->input->post('tempat_lahir_tersangka1'),
        'tgl_lahir'=>$this->input->post('tanggal_lahir_tersangka1'),
        'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jns_kelamin_tersangka1'),
        'pekerjaan'=>$this->input->post('pekerjaan_tersangka1'),
        'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat_tersangka1'),
        'telp'=>$this->input->post('telp_tersangka1'),
        'agama'=>$this->input->post('agama_tersangka1'),
        'kewarganegaraan'=>$this->input->post('warga_negara_tersangka1'));
        if ($this->input->post('saksi1')){
        $data3=array(
        'nama_saksi'=>$this->input->post('saksi1'),
        'tempat_lahir'=>$this->input->post('tempat_lahir_saksi1'),
        'tgl_lahir'=>$this->input->post('tanggal_lahir_saksi1'),
        'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jns_kelamin_saksi1'),
        'pekerjaan'=>$this->input->post('pekerjaan_saksi1'),
        'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat_saksi1'),
        'telp'=>$this->input->post('telp_saksi1'),
        'agama'=>$this->input->post('agama_saksi1'),
        'kewarganegaraan'=>$this->input->post('warga_negara_saksi1'));
        $this->m_data->add_lp($data,$data1,$data3);}
        else {
            $this->m_data->add_lp1($data,$data1);
        }
    }
    else if($this->input->post('saksi1')){
        $data3=array(
        'nama_saksi'=>$this->input->post('saksi1'),
        'tempat_lahir'=>$this->input->post('tempat_lahir_saksi1'),
        'tgl_lahir'=>$this->input->post('tanggal_lahir_saksi1'),
        'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jns_kelamin_saksi1'),
        'pekerjaan'=>$this->input->post('pekerjaan_saksi1'),
        'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat_saksi1'),
        'telp'=>$this->input->post('telp_saksi1'),
        'agama'=>$this->input->post('agama_saksi1'),
        'kewarganegaraan'=>$this->input->post('warga_negara_saksi1'));
        if (!$this->input->post('pelaku1')){
            $this->m_data->add_lp1($data,$data3);
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->m_data->input_data('laporan_polisi',$data);
    }
    redirect(base_url().'admin/LP_B');
```

that's my controller

```
function add_lp1($data, $data1){
    $this->db->trans_start();

    $sql1="insert into laporan_polisi(jenis_LP,nama_pelapor,tempat_lahir,tgl_lahir,jenis_kelamin,pekerjaan,alamat,telp,agama,kewarganegaraan, tgl_kejadian, waktu_kejadian, tempat_kejadian, yang_terjadi, bagaimana_terjadi, uraian_kejadian, tindak_pidana, barang_bukti, kerugian, tgl_laporan, jam_lapor, petugas)
        values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?,?)";

    $this->db->query($sql1,$data);
    $id_lp=$this->db->insert_id();

    $sql2="insert into tersangka(nama_tersangka,tempat_lahir, tgl_lahir, jenis_kelamin, pekerjaan, alamat, telp, agama, kewarganegaraan, id_lp)
        values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,$id_lp)";
    $this->db->query($sql2,$data1);

    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

function add_lp2($data, $data3){
    $this->db->trans_start();

    $sql1="insert into laporan_polisi(jenis_LP,nama_pelapor,tempat_lahir,tgl_lahir,jenis_kelamin,pekerjaan,alamat,telp,agama,kewarganegaraan, tgl_kejadian, waktu_kejadian, tempat_kejadian, yang_terjadi, bagaimana_terjadi, uraian_kejadian, tindak_pidana, barang_bukti, kerugian, tgl_laporan, jam_lapor, petugas)
        values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?,?)";

    $this->db->query($sql1,$data);
    $id_lp=$this->db->insert_id();

    $sql3="insert into saksi(nama_saksi,tempat_lahir, tgl_lahir, jenis_kelamin, pekerjaan, alamat, telp, agama, kewarganegaraan, id_lp)
        values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,$id_lp)";
    $this->db->query($sql3,$data3);

    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

function input_data($data,$table){
    $this->db->insert($table,$data);
}
```

and my model_data
i need more info about check the field (not use isset).